# If I insert a comment on a source code will it`s binarries MD5 be changed?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, md5

I`m just wondering....
If it was the case that I was thinking in creating different reseases for each custumer that I sold my software, could I check each one with MD5 just changing a comment inside the source code and recompiling? I mean, will a ##comment inside a C++, C# or java code change the binnary MD5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are removed early in (or before) the compilation process, so inserting a comment will not change the hash of the compiled binary.

The only exception (that I can think of) is if your binaries include line numbers, which can change based on comments. Typically this happens when you're compiling in debug mode, but you can also force it using something like the `__LINE__` macro in C++. But even in this case, the content of the comment is irrelevant, only how many lines it takes up (so you might as well just use blank lines for that purpose). Besides, released software probably shouldn't include that information.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. In C/C++ comments are not stripped they are replaced with space - wont affect binaries. But there are at least one other way it may affect the binary.

Comment: Yes, you say it only happens in debugcompiled binaries. This is not true.

Comment: its not about how one feel. Its all about factual answers. And actually this __LINE__ issues not an exception its relevant in prety much all C/C++ projects. Have you ever seen an assert without line number? It would just be silly :) The real answer is probably "Yes it is very plausible it will change the binary however the logic will be the same".

Comment: Assertions are practically the canonical example of a construct that only occurs in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, the binary changes for *every* build, if there is for instance a build timestamp.  This could provide the traceability you want.  However, comments should not affect the MD5 of a release mode binary, unless your compiler is buggy.

Comment: Theres nothing buggy with a compiler that builds a different binary with added comments if its needed.

Comment: @stefan, I clarified that I was thinking of release mode.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no. Comments are stripped out very early in the compilation process.

The longer answer is, sometimes - but not reliably. There's a number of foreseeable reasons that vestiges (more like side-effects) of the comment could show up. However, those are fragile at best.

I assume this is for some sort of automated process, like selling the software on a website. How about outputting a header file like "user.h" that simply specifies the name/email/username/etc as a #define'd string, and then printing that somewhere in your program's About screen (both for the user's benefit and so the compiler doesn't optimize it away)? It requires you to recompile your program for each user, but that may not be a problem if it only takes a few seconds to build.

Answer (score 1):

A comment cannot be compiled to a cpu opcode so it will not change the hash of the blob.

Comment: No but it does affect line numbers and when a file was modified etc etc.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes** it can change the binaries.

For example in C/C++ there's the  **LINE** macro for instance. If this is used in the code it will change the binary if you add or remove a line with comment.